# Unity - How to check version of Google Mobile Ads in my project

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I got the notification from Admob that I have to update Google mobile ads to the newest version. But I don't know what version in my current project. How to verify that?

Comment: Run games source in Xcode, see console log. It says which version of Admob used.

Comment: I have tested your solution in Android Studio, but I can't see it. Can you tell me the keyword to search it on the log ?

Comment: sorry don't know about Android Studio..I used Xcode/iPhone